# GitHub found vulnerabilities (when pushing to github) - but /network/alerts doesn't exist?

Tags: git, github

How to address correctly so warning no longer applies or appears ?

This functionality (check for vulnerabilities) is part of a beta program.
Not sure how to proceed.

I get:

```
git push
...
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 822 bytes | 822.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
...
remote: GitHub found 9 vulnerabilities on durrantm/rspec_selenium_template's default branch (1 critical, 2 high, 5 moderate, 1 low). To find out more, visit:
remote:      https://github.com/durrantm/rspec_selenium_template/network/alerts
remote: 
To github.com:durrantm/rspec_selenium_template.git
   94f9643..492f209  master -> master
```

I am stuck because:

- I don't have that directory locally.
- In github I **do** seem to have a `/network` page (as shown below) but I **don't** have a `/network/alerts` page (I get a 404)

[image]

fyi The security tab doesn't show anything:

UPDATE - that was becuase I was not signed in (not obvious).
Once I signed in I can see it - but still no info that I need:

I can disable it by clicking on the link to turn off this beta program:

[image]

But how to I actually address (or even see) them

[image]

Comment: The "Network" tab is unrelated to a `/network` directory you might have. The network of your repo is a visual map of who has forked it. Click on the "Code" tab at the top to see whether you have a `/network` dir.